# How to pass the variable in pagination for cakephp

Tags: pagination, cakephp-2.0

I am confused with the passing the variable in pagination without giving the name of model.

Can it possible to pass array directly without passing Model?

This is my code

foreach($search_data as $data)
        {
            $city_data[] = $data['Search_city']['city'];
        }

```
    $this->paginate = array(

             'limit' => 2
    );

    $locList = $this->paginate('Post');

    $this->set('locList_data', $locList);
```

If I run this code then, It works fine.

But, I want to pass the array which was in $city_data.

If I do like this Then, It doesn't works.

Please suggest me, what can i do??

Thanx,

shashikant chobhe

Comment: can it possible to pass variable like this                                                                                                               $locList = $this->paginate($city_data);

Comment: what's content $search_data array?

Comment: Its just a normal array like as->                                Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Search_city] => Array
                (
                    [country] => india
                    [countryCode] => IN
                    [state] => maharashtra
                    [stateProvinceCode] => MH
                    [city] => aurangabad
                    [description] => great city
                    [id] => 5
                    [hotel_list] => 
                    [number_of_nights] => 2
                    [sorting_data] => Star Rating
                )

        )

Comment: What are you want to do? tell me clearly.

Answer (score -1):

You will need a model to use the Pagination Function in Cake. However, 
to do what you want to do, there are two options:

> 1. Create your own pagination.
> 2. Create a model and override the pagination method in there.

If you are familiar with cake, then I would recommend you to go with 
Option 2, else option 1 is probably what you want to do.

Comment: sorry but, I am not understand what u said just.                                                                                                               can you explain it deeply?